# displaying different contents in specified time interval in php?

Tags: php

how to solve and display different contents in specified 3 hour time interval in php?
let's say the default content should be displayed at 8am, and then the next new content should be at 11am, the 3rd batch should be at 2pm, and then the content will return to the first batch

```
$firstbatch = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'8:00am');
$contentvariable = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a simple if/else statement

here's some psuedocode for the overall idea

```
if(time >= 11am && time < 2pm){
    $content = '11am content';
}
elseif(time >= 2pm && time < 8am){
    $content = '2pm content';
}
else{
    $content = 'default content';
}
```